# WSO2 Developing Custom Endpoint

Tags: wso2, customization, load-balancing, endpoint

i need to extend the LoadBalance Endpoint developing my custom endpoint.
I tried:

1)

```
 public class CustomLoadBalanceEndpoint extends LoadbalanceEndpoint
```

2) i exported it using wso2 studio in the /repository/components/dropins folder

3) i cannot find the way to use it inside ESB... I tried with this code

```
<endpoint class="it.innovapuglia.sistemapuglia.wso2.enpoint.CustomLoadBalanceEndpoint"
               algorithm="org.apache.synapse.endpoints.algorithms.RoundRobin">
    <endpoint name="tomcat1">
           <address uri="http://localhost:8080/RestService/rest/servizio"/>
    </endpoint>
</endpoint>
```

but ESB doesn't accept it saying me "Proxy service requires a valid in sequence or a valid endpoint."

Answer (score 0):

You can not use your endpoint like that.
After developing your custom endpoint keep that in the repository/components/lib folder.You have to call your endpoint like this;

```
<endpoint name="CustomEndpoint">
                    <class name="org.wso2.carbon.endpoint.CustomLoadBalanceEndpoint">

                    </class>
</endpoint>
```

Check the following posts on how to add your custom endpoint concepts.

[1]http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2012/07/class-endpoints-in-synapse.html
[2]http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/06/class-endpointssample.html

Comment: Already tried referring to those posts. I cannot save in the endpoint list an endpoint with that configuration. It says me: Invalid Configuration. Did you succeed in this?

Comment: We do not have UI support. Waht you have to do is, keep your jar in the lib folder and add the class endpoint from SOurceview..It should work. What do you mean by "I cannot save in the endpoint list an endpoint with that configuration" ..?

Comment: Oh ok, i see. Yes i mean what you said before. In my work context i need to have full control by UI too. Indeed i tried to save a custom endpoint using UI in the source view and adding your code with class tag pointing to my jar in the repository/components/lib. It says me "Cannot create class endpoint "

Comment: sure..will consider the UI support in future

Comment: Sorry i changed my post before... yes... useful the future support. But the step i did are:
1) develped the endpoint
2) saving the jar in components/lib
3) going in the endpoint section ---> add enpoint ---> source view---> pasted your code.
4) esb says me Cannot create class endpoint 
What i'm wrong?

Comment: After copying the jar to lib folder, you need to restart the server..Then only particular class will be available in the classpath..If you do above settings and if you still face issue..paste the whole error stack here